# What services do ports keep opened?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

> sudo ufw status

```
sudo: ufw: command not found
```

> netstat -ntlp

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State       
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN
...
```

> sudo iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I want to understand what allows to open these ports? I want to change this configuration but via **ufw** I cannot do this. So I decided to delete any configuration of firewall doing **sudo apt-get remove ufw** and **sudo iptables -F**. What opens these ports?

Comment: **sudo** `netstat -nlptu`. Without `sudo`, `netstat` cannot show which process is listening. And you probably want UDP ports too. Anyway, as far as I can see you have only `sshd` listening on port 22 and a web server listening on port 80; the others are listening on the localhost address, so they cannot receive data from the Internet (and `iptables` and `ufw` cannot control them).

Comment: Great thanks! I understood. They were sshd and nginx, services that open ports. But sincerely my initial problem is that I `sudo ufw allow 8000` but `netstat -ntlpu` doesn't see this change. I cannot acces to this port from out.

Comment: But *who* is supposed to be listening on port 8000? `ufw allow` instructs `ufw` that *if* a process listens on port 8000 then clients are to be allowed to connect; it does not magically open the port.

Comment: Yep. Your answer above sorted out it for me all. Thanks!